# any sample example for IISCreation with SSL using C#?

Tags: c#

was getting error while trying below for creating site.

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var certificate = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "localhost", true);
X509Certificate x509Certificate = certificate[0];
//iHashCode = x509Certificate.GetHashCode();
store.Close();

Site.Add(string name, string bindingInformation, string physicalPath, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objCertificate[0].GetHashCode()), string certificateStore,objX509Certificate.GetName());
```

Error:

> A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated

Comment: It looks like you are either the Server is not running or calling by wrong name or you are getting an error when connecting to the server.  A request is being made by application to the server and no response or a bad status is being returned (like 401, or 501).  Normally a good status is 200 OK.  So I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to get more details on the actual status being returned.  If you have a working application than compare the first request headers in working and non working.

Comment: This snippet won't even compile. Post the *actual* code, and the full exception text. You're asking people to guess where that error came from. The error says nothing about SSL and certificates, it says you haven't logged on. I'd guess you're trying to create a site on a remote IIS server but forgot to add the credentials to whatever class you use for this